# If loop being ignored

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a Python programm that is ignoring the if loop.
Could somebody please help me by telling me what I did wrong?
Please see the code below:

```html
class Check():
  def __init__(self, op1, op2, op):
            self.op1 = op1
            self.op2 = op2
            self.op = op


  def main():

        print("Enter first number: ")
        num1 = int(input())
        print("Enter second number: ")
        num2 = int(input())
        print("Enter operation: ")
        op=str(input())
        if op == '+':
            return op1 + op2
        elif op == '-':
            return op1 - op2
        elif op == '*':
            return op1 * op2
        elif op == '/':
            return op1 / op2

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Well, first of all `if` is not a loop. Second, your code just defines a class but no instance or method are ever created/called

Comment: Where is your main driver? What's the input the user gives it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is there is nothing that is op1 and op2, there is self.op1, self.op2, num1, and num2. I am assuming you want to add num1 and num2. Also you didn't put

```
self
```

in cheese, here is the working program

```
class Check():
    def __init__(self, op1, op2, op):
            self.op1 = op1
            self.op2 = op2
            self.op = op


    def cheese(self):
        print("Enter first number: ")
        op1 = int(input())
        print("Enter second number: ")
        op2 = int(input())
        print("Enter operation: ")
        op=str(input())
        if op == '+':
            return op1 + op2
        elif op == '-':
            return op1 - op2
        elif op == '*':
            return op1 * op2
        elif op == '/':
            return op1 / op2
a = Check(1,2,"+")
print(a.cheese())
```

Comment: Hello the code was edited to include a main()  function.  I now get an error that main() is not defined.

Comment: Again you need to put self, as its part of a class, then you have to initialize Check with something like  'a = Check()'  then because main is part of the Check class you would say 'a.main()' it might not make sense to you now, but i'm sure in a while you will understand it.